# vb.net-2010 + mysql workbench time and day conflict

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, vb.net-2010

need help for vb10 + mysql workbench time and day conflict. i tried to look for answers on other questions but i can't really understand what to do.

here is my code.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=baby;database=database"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        Mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from database.testclass where Room='" & cbrm.Text & "' and Day='" & cbday.Text & "' and Start='" & cbstart.Text & "' and End='" & cbend.Text & "'"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Mysqlconn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            If cbrm.Text = Reader.GetString("Room") And cbday.Text = Reader.GetString("Day") And cbstart.Text >= Reader.GetString("Start") And cbend.Text < Reader.GetString("End") Then
                MessageBox.Show("There is/are conflict/s")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("There is/are no conflict/s")
            End If
        End While

            Mysqlconn.Close() 
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

when i press the button, it should check if there are/is conflict. but it's not working. what do you think is the problem?

thank you guys. i really need this.

Comment: That questions seems to be purely about MySQL data types. It's not related to VB.net nor MySQL Workbench. Rewrite it to make it clearer what you need. Leave out anything that is not related.

Comment: i rewrote it already. can you understand it now? thank you